# Order table being read as ORDER command by the compiler

Tags: sql, postgresql, keyword

I have this sql statment stored in a string variable

```
SELECT
    o.id_order,
    o.registerdate,
    i.latest_invoice,
    d.latest_delivery 
  FROM
    order o 
  JOIN
    (
      SELECT
        id_address,
        max(registerdate) as latest_invoice 
      FROM
        invoice 
      GROUP BY
        id_address
    ) i     
      ON o.id_address = i.id_address  
  JOIN
    (
      SELECT
        id_address,
        max(registerdate) as latest_delivery 
      FROM
        delivery 
      GROUP BY
        id_address
    ) d      
      ON o.id_address = d.id_address  
  WHERE
    o.id_address = '189'
```

When I execute the query   I get an error at the position of `order o`, because the compiler thinks that it is the ORDER BY command. Do you know how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using reserved keywords as table names, but if you insist you [have to use double quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

```
from "order" o
```

Note that with double quotes the name is case-sensitive. Depending on how you created that table, you might need `"ORDER"` or `"Order"`. In `psql` you should check the correct case using the `\d` command.